# ajax 'GET' call returns jsonp okay but callback produces 'undefined' data

Tags: jquery, get, jsonp

I'm accessing a cross-domain webservice utilizing an.ajax jquery call from an html page.  While I can see the jsonp data using firebug, I am not able to load it into a variable or even display it (for debugging purposes).  Attempts to retrieve data using the jsonpCallback, success and complete functions always result in 'undefined' / null data.

Ultimately, I need to save the data to variables.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        User: UserValue,
        GUID: GUIDValue
    },
    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp", // tried json
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonp: false,  // tried true
    jsonpCallback: function (saveData) {
        if (saveData == null) {
            alert("DATA IS UNDEFINED!");  // displays every time
        }
        alert("Success is " + saveData);  // 'Success is undefined'
    },
    url: "http://localhost/NotifMOD/NotifService.svc/GetAllMessages?callback=success?",
    async: false, // tried true
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    },
    complete: function (a, b) {
        alert(a); //[object Object]
        alert(b); // parseerror
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In JSONP you must define your function in your code.

jsonpCallback must be the name of this function, not a function.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You do it like this :

```
function receive(saveData) {
    if (saveData == null) {
            alert("DATA IS UNDEFINED!");  // displays every time
    }
    alert("Success is " + saveData);  // 'Success is undefined'
}

$.ajax({
    data: {
        User: UserValue,
        GUID: GUIDValue
    },
    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp", // tried json
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonp: false,  // tried true
    jsonpCallback: "receive",
    url: "http://localhost/NotifMOD/NotifService.svc/GetAllMessages?callback=receive?",
    async: false, // tried true
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply "dystroy".  I tried your suggestion (with the addition of changing the URL to _http://localhost/NotifMOD/NotifiService.svc/GetAllMessages?callback=jsonpCallback?).  Now the error function: 'errorThrown' parameter is returning "Error: receive was not called.

Comment: The name of the function (here "receive") must be the one at the beginning of the jsonp answer. There was an error in my code (assuming the server uses the "callback" parameter). The url should end with "callback=receive".

Comment: Maybe it'll help you : an open source code I make. Client : https://github.com/Canop/braldop/blob/master/chrome/braldop/inext_com.js  and server : https://github.com/Canop/braldop/blob/master/go/src/braldopserver/BraldopServer.go

Comment: @Jake This answer is from 2012, that is a time where JSONP still made sense. It's now 2017, JSONP is dead. If you find an API requiring you to use JSONP, use another API.