# Get JSON with AJAX in javascript returning NULL instead of JSON object

Tags: javascript, ajax

When i attempt to retrieve a JSON with ajax i first had problems with CORS which i fixed by enabling crossDomain to true and adding dataType as jsonp (notice the 'p').
When running the script it returns a null instead of the data it was supposed to get from the JSON

```
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var json = (function() {
        var json = [];
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'crossDomain': true,
            'method': "get",
            'url': "products.json",
            'dataType': "jsonp",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    })();
console.log(json);



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSON

```
{
    "items": [{
        "title": "Express"
    }, {
        "title": "Unexpress"
    }]
}
```

I expect a json but it returns null and a message in console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" at line 2 of the JSON.

Comment: Where are you getting JSON from ?

Comment: The hard drive. It will get the json from c:\products.json

Comment: forget the last comment, i get it from the project root

Comment: Well, try to open Inspector (ctrl + shift + i) and go to network tab, and refresh page and look what you get there, there should be a request for it

Comment: Yes, i do get it with status "finished"

Comment: ```$.get( "products.json", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});``` try this

Comment: I can read the response too there.

Comment: Well, try `console.log(json)` before `return json` maybe you should use other name for variable inside IIFE

Comment: i added what you suggested and an extra "$.get( "products.json", 'crossDomain': true, function( data ) { console.log(data); });" so it would not spam me with CORS problem and now it returns Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: about the console.log(json) suggestion, it still returns null.

Comment: The majority of the ajax options you are using were completely made irrelevant upon adding `dataType: 'jsonp'`

Comment: Or sorry, I meant console.log(data) in success function, there should be your json object

Comment: Clearly, the service you are using doesn't support JSONP. so, stop using it and deal with the CORS problem. This is clearly an X/Y problem. you just threw every ajax option you could at it not understanding what they do.

Comment: Thats why i am trying to get help. I used JSONP to get around CORS, but without it i will be prompted with a CORS problem which i don't know how to handle.

Comment: i used https instead to get around it, i wanted to use FILE but i used HTTPS instead and it works. thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891389/load-a-json-file-in-local-system-using-jquery-javascript/38893424#38893424

Answer (score 0):

You havent defined `jsonpcallback`, refer to below link this may help

[ajax 'GET' call returns jsonp okay but callback produces 'undefined' data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320619/ajax-get-call-returns-jsonp-okay-but-callback-produces-undefined-data)

Answer (score 0):

Change 'dataType': "jsonp", to 'dataType': "json",

Comment: that will prompt me a Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///{MY_PATH}/products.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: @userct if you would have stated that in your question, we could have solved this problem for you a long time ago. ***What you are doing is impossible***. Literally impossible, as in there is no way that you will ever use ajax to get json from your filesystem using a standard web browser.

Comment: The best you can do is convert the .json file into a .js file that calls a method, and include it like any other or use the jsoncallback param to tell jquery the name of the method within the .js file.

Comment: Do you need to config cors in your back-end to work